# How can I change the type of objects' _id field to ObjectId in the MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I have a few objects in a MongoDB database where the `_id` field was assigned an integer by mistake, how can I in the MongoDB shell replace these integers with an ObjectId?

An example of such an object would look like this:

```
{ "_id" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I found was to clone each each object to another with an ObjectId value assigned to `_id`, and then delete all objects with an integer for `_id`. I did the following in the shell:

```
// $type: 16 means int32
> db.Roles.find({_id: {$type: 16}}).forEach(function (x) {
          x._id = ObjectId();
          db.Roles.save(x);
      })
> db.Roles.remove({_id: {$type: 16}})
```

Comment: Yea that's probably the best way, of course you cannot update the `_id` field so you do have to write it out again.